# Handle File upload, resize with Pillow, Store with SQLAlchemy, Serve File with Flask

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, python-imaging-library

So I am trying to handle a file upload then store that file as a binary into the database. After I store it I try to serve the file at a given URL. I can't seem to find a method that works here. I need to use a database because I am hosting with Google app engine. Here is a few relevant parts of my code.

Serving Handler:

```
@app.route('/photo/<path:filename>')
def uploaded_photo(filename):
    try:
        photo = db_session.query(Photo)\
            .filter_by(filename=filename).one()
    except:
        return 'There was an error with the photo.'

    return send_file(
        io.BytesIO(photo.image_blob),
        attachment_filename=photo.filename,
        mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

How I store my image using Pillow.

```
Photo(
    filename=filename,
    image_blob=image.tobytes()))
```

The Photo Model:

```
class Photo(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'photos'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    item_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('item.id'))
    filename = Column(String)
    image_blob = Column(LargeBinary)
    item = relationship("Item", back_populates="photos")
```

What happens is that when you load the Image url, /photo/. A blank photo appears. However, the upload part goes smoothly.

Comment: Check the HTTP response when you request that photo. What is the actual response? A "blank image" is not very precise. As a side note, if your images are relatively large, you should consider using a file storage service instead of storing it all as binary blobs in the database. It scales much better that way.

Comment: The response is \xffd8ffe000104a4649460001010000.....c51455a31206a6375a28a19513ffd9 .

Comment: That's not very helpful. It's not the entire response. An HTTP response includes the status code as well as the headers. Try running `curl -v [url]` and including the output here.

Comment: Why are you passing `photo.image_blob` through an `io.BytesIO`? If you do - don't you need to call a `get_value()` of it?

Comment: @DanCornilescu `photo.image_blob` is already a byte string. It does not contain the method `getvalue()`

Answer (score -1):

Dont store images on the database rather use a static folder where you can save the files. just save the documents name and details on the database for file retrieval. 
You can check this documentation. [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/fileuploads/) for uploading.... Here is for downloading... [link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/)